# Importing a module which imports from same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a project set up as follows:

```
myproject/
  setup.py
  myproject/
    __init__.py
    module1/
      __init__.py
      a.py
      b.py
      test/
        __init__.py
        test.py
```

In `a.py` I have:

```
from b import Something
```

In `test.py` I have:

```
from myproject.module1 import a
```

When I run `test.py` I get a `ImportError` because `b` cannot be found - since test.py is in a different directory.

I know I can fix this in `a.py` by writing `from myproject.module1.b import Something`, but this seems far too verbose to do throughout the project.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you need a `__init__.py` in myproject as well? Is this path in the `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: @Alex Yes, edited (apologies). The `myproject` that is the parent of `module1` is on the PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from myproject.module1.b import Something` is the best way to do it. It may be a little verbose, but it is explicit which is generally a desirable quality in Pythonic code.

Comment: While both Freaky Dug and @Evert are correct, this is the better solution based on the [PEP8 style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): "Relative imports for intra-package imports are highly discouraged. Always use the absolute package path for all imports"

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use

```
from .b import Something
```

Since that's relative, it should always work.

See http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

Comment: I'm aware of that, but it seems like a hacky fix. Also, PEP8: "Relative imports for intra-package imports are highly discouraged."

Answer (score 1):

You can try [relative imports](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) in `a.py`, e.g.

```
from .b import Something
```

But this may not be a complete solution to your problem. As with any modules that `import` modules/packages in a higher level of the directory structure, you have to be careful how you run it. Specifically, running a module as `python submodule.py` implicitly sets the module's `__name__` variable to `"__main__"`. Since imports (relative and absolute alike) depend on that `__name__` and the `PYTHONPATH`, running a submodule directly may make imports behave differently (or break, as in your case).

Try running your `tests.py` as

```
python myproject/module1/test/test.py
```

*from the top level of the package* instead of running it directly.